Grouping heatmap by a third variable in R ggplot2
I would like to make a heatmap where I order and group the y axis by another variable, for example using this code I can make a heatmap showing carats across cut and color
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, color, fill=carat))+
  geom_tile()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_ipsum()

I would like to also group color by clarity and show this on the output- is there a way to do that

You could achieve this by creating a combined factor of color and clarity, and plot it on the y-axis.
diamonds$clarity_color <- factor(with(diamonds, paste(clarity, color, sep = "_")),
                             levels = with(diamonds, unique(paste(clarity, color, sep = "_")[order(clarity, color)])))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, clarity_color, fill = carat)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  labs(y = "clarity + colour")

